# Does the Bravely Default Japanese version come with English audio or subtitles?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, bravely-default

I am living in Japan with a Japanese 3DS and want to pick up a copy of Bravely Default. My Japanese can order me a coffee, but not get me through a RPG..

So does the game (specifically the Japanese version) have the option to swap language (for audio, or even just subtitles).

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to work out the Japanese for "Tactics", "Config" and "Language". You will find it by opening the menu and going in that order (Menu -> Tactics -> Config -> Language).

You can't do this before having gone through the intro however, but once you have saved your settings, you can restart the game in those settings.

Comment: Awesome! I had read that was available on the English version (to be able to swap back to Japanese audio) but wasn't sure it was available on the Japanese version

Comment: @Chris Apparently, it's the same in all versions, just that each version is defaulted to the local language. I can't confirm this, so hopefully you can!

Comment: I will pick it up tomorrow and comment here

Comment: Confirmed, it was indeed under Menu -> Tactics -> Config -> Language. Even better I can choose to listen to the Japanese with English subtitles, or vice versa, very cool. And a cool game so far!